# How to specify "Admin Approved" users for a Connected App?

Tags: canvas, connected-apps

I've created a canvas app as a "Connected App" inside Salesforce, and set the approval to "Admin Approved" so that I can receive a POST signed request - however I cannot actually figure out how to assign users to the app.

As an administrator, how do I configure which users are allowed to access the connected app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/quick_start_config_who_can_access_canvas_app.htm

> In your connected application you will see related list where you can configure both profiles and permission sets allowed to pre-authorize your connected application

Comment: Ah - so obvious..... I was under the misunderstanding that you specified users explicitly, not profiles. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesDavies you can specify users also through permission sets .Thanks